# Laravel Migrate to AWS RDS using Lambda

Tags: laravel, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, serverless-framework, bref

I am looking to deploy a `Laravel` app on `AWS Lambda`. The app requires a `PostgreSQL` database access.

The idea is am using `Bref` to deploy on AWS Lambda. I created a RDS PostgreSQL  database manually and updated the inbound rule and added the connection parameter to the .env file and serverless.yml template in the app.

After deploying the app I am receiving error `SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table`. I belive the problem is that no migration occurred. So the question is how to migrate from Laravel/Lambda to RDS? Shall I use the artisan and the CLI? Or there is a way to create an automated way to migrate?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you don't make a custom setting for Postgresql, by default the sql queries should be like this

```
SELECT * FROM database_name.table_name
```

There are two options or you should specify the table names in all your laravel model files as below

```
protected $table = 'database_name.table';
```

or you should connect to rds postgresql via terminal and set the following

```
SET search_path TO database_name,public;
```

[postgresql schemas](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/ddl-schemas.html)